# I want to add the marks of each courses in their specific textboxes, but I dont know the expression. What might be the solution?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL08V.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utjAx.png)

I am building a report. I want to add marks of specific CourseID into the Obtained marks column. I have CourseStudentMarksTable and have shown relationship in the picture First, and the report in picture Second

I dont know what I am supposed to do? If there is a better alternative please do help

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO. It does not have code for analysis. It appears to be a design issue. Suggest you post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Your table structure is good.  You have two many to many relationships.  The next step is to learn how to enter data into your tables.  You enter data into the tables using forms for all sorts of very good reasons.  Access can auto build forms for you.  One at a time, select each table in the side-panel and then hit create-form on the ribbon.  You should get about 5 slightly different forms for entering data.  Spend time learning how to add and edit data in the tables with the forms.  When you are ready and have some data move on to the query designer and play to make (~Second)